# Custom file to store many url strings on the iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios, url, xcode4, nsstring

My app needs many NSStrings containing differente hard coded web URLs, to be accessed according to user's choice.

I'm looking for a convenient way to store all of these strings in one place, not being a custom Class.

I was reading about `NSLocalizedString`, that stores many strings on a `.string` file for localizations purposes, and I was wondering if I could create a custom `.string` file, like `URLs.string`.

Is that possible, to have a custom `URLs.string` file? If so, how to access the strings on it, like I would if it were a localized file `self.titleLabel.text = NSLocalizedString(@"TITLE", nil);`

Is this the best approach? Any other better idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That probably isn't the best way to do it. If you want to have some strings stored that will be distributed withe the app, use a plist file. If these are strings that are discovered (downloaded from a server, entered by a user), use NSUserDefaults.

If you want to ship some but modify them later, that can be done with a plist. Just write the modified copy in the documents dir and check for that before reading the bundle plist.

Comment: OK, I'll be checking the .plist documentation. Do you know of any tutorial online? I'll be googling it too. Thanks for your answer and time!

Answer (score 1):

So, i also needs manage a lot of url strings and i found a solution to imitate NSLocalizedString's staff:

```
//.pch
#define URL(key) \
[[NSDictionary dictionaryWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"URLs" ofType:@"strings"]] objectForKey:key]

//URLs.strings
"testUrl" = "test.com";

//Usage
NSString *string = URL(@"testUrl");
```

that's isn't best solution, but very easy to use.